# "Error displaying the error page" joomla

Tags: joomla

сайт работал нормально. утром пришел выдает ошибку "Error displaying the error page" и больше ничего. подскажите хотя бы в каком направлении искать.
на сервере ошибка login: ERROR 145(HY000) at line 1: Table './admin_***/p7u9t_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired.
joomla3.x debian7 php5.4

Answer (score 0):

для начала, обратитесь к службе поддержки хостинга, тут конечно много вариантов, возможно нет подключения с базой данных(проверьте файл configuration.php если правильно прописано база данных и пароль, пользователь), может обновляли движок

Comment: сервер на работе стоит.